# How do I do this OnClientClick="jpcPrint(<%= this.Controller.JPId %>);"... so that it works

Tags: asp.net

When i try to

```
OnClientClick="jpcPrint(<%= this.Controller.JPId %>);"
```

for a button, <%= this.Controller.JPId %> is literally put into the html rather than being evaluated. How do i write some version of the above such that the html would read:

```
onclick="jpcPrint(49);"
```

for example instead of

```
onclick="jpcPrint(<%= this.Controller.JPId %>);"
```

<%= this.Controller.JPId %> evaluates perfectly well when placed elsewhere on the page including in a gridview above this button. For example this works fine:

```
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="Autocompleteextender1" MinimumPrefixLength="4" CompletionInterval="1000"
                CompletionSetCount="10" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" ContextKey="<%# this.Controller.JPId %>"
                TargetControlID="txtLKey" runat="server" CompletionListCssClass="jpcKeyList" >
```

So this.Controller.JPId is not the issue. Seems to be something about the way such statement are evaluated within button attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in the code behind of the page or control, and then you can call to that function

### Examples:

Return a simple value

In the code behind

```
protected string GetJPCPrint()
{
 return "jpcPrint(" & this.Controller.JPId.ToString() & ");";
}
```

in the html code

```
OnClientClick="'<%= GetJPCPrint() %>'"
```

---

In a bound control (grid etc)

```
protected string SourceValue(object data)
{
 string value = "";
if (data != null)
{
 BusinessLayer.Comment comment = (BusinessLayer.Comment)data;
 value = comment.OtherComment.Source.Name;

}
return value;
}
```

in the html code

```
Text='<%# SourceValue(Container.DataItem) %>'
```

---

I hope it help you.

Comment: Hi, that doesnt actually work... for me anyway. Youve just replaced the problem code with a wrapper for the problem code. i.e. when i run that the ouputted html is onclick="<%= GetJPCPrint() %>"

Answer (score 0):

1. look at your page's source to see exactly what was written out to the browser.
2. one thing i see is you didn't include quotes, so jcPrint( id ) would not work in any browser accept for IE.

i would suggest not making your button a server control (not including runat=server).

```
<button value="my button" click="jpcPrint('<%= this.Controller.JPId %>')" />
```

there are infinite ways to do this.. you could also create a local function, and than once you're ready call the asp.net postback function if you need to postback afterwards.

Comment: The output is just the literal i.e. click="jpcPrint('<%= this.Controller.JPId %>')". Im not sure what you mean about the quotes. JPId is a long and it does work in IE, FF, Chrome, Safari. In the end I did change some functionality so I could forgo  a server control and just used standard html <input .. > to get around the problem and the <% %> does evaluate properly within the attribute then. But if i needed a server control I wondered why it wouldnt evaluate properly.

Comment: like what you typed here just now, has the single quotes ' ' around the JPId.
your original post doesn't include them.

Comment: Oh, I just copied what you typed for my comment. Not sure what you mean by quotes being neccesary for cross browser compatibility for longs although if you thought JPId was a string i get what you mean.